# EditText with top extraspace problem when background is null programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have a Textinputlayout where the ediText  background is set to null in layout xml:

android:background="@null"

[image]

the problem is when set the background to null programatelly

tilState.background=null

the hint title have extra space:

[image]

Comment: **tilState** it's object of EditText or TextInputLayout?

Comment: tilState is TextInputLayout...best regards

Answer (score 1):

I fix recreating the xml layout with recreate() function